# nest js CacheModule with 'cache-manager-ioredis-yet creates redis connection every request

Tags: nestjs, ioredis

```
import { Inject, Logger, MiddlewareConsumer, Module, NestModule } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppController, HeaderController, FooterController, RedisAPIController, MetadataController, HealthzController } from './controller';

import { HttpModule } from '@nestjs/axios';
import { InitialLoadService } from './service/initialLoad.service';
import { IsRedisCluster, redisPassword, redisPort, redisUrl } from '@config';
import { RedisModule } from '@modules/redis/redis.module';
import { redisStore } from 'cache-manager-ioredis-yet';
import { RedisStore } from "cache-manager-ioredis-yet";
import { Cache } from 'cache-manager';
import { SetUserContextMiddleware } from '@middleware';
import { CACHE_MANAGER, CacheModule } from '@nestjs/cache-manager';


@Module({
    imports: [
        CacheModule.register({
    isGlobal: true,
    // @ts-ignore
    store: async () => await redisStore({
        host: redisUrl,
        password: redisPassword,
        port: +redisPort,
        tls: {
            host: redisUrl,
            passphrase: redisPassword
        },
    }
    ),
}),
        RedisModule,
        HttpModule,
    ],
    controllers: [AppController, HeaderController, FooterController, RedisAPIController, MetadataController, HealthzController],
    providers: [InitialLoadService],

})


export class AppModule implements NestModule {
    private readonly logger = new Logger('Redis Events');
    private readonly redisStore: RedisStore;

    constructor(@Inject(CACHE_MANAGER) readonly cacheManager: Cache) {
        console.log('in app module constructor')
        this.redisStore = cacheManager.store as unknown as RedisStore;
    }

    configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer) {
        consumer.apply(SetUserContextMiddleware).forRoutes(AppController, MyGarageAPIController);

    }

    onModuleInit(): void {
        const client = this.redisStore.client;


        if (!client) {
            this.logger.error('no redis client initialised');
        }


        client.on('connect', () => {
            this.logger.log('redis client is connecting to server...');
        });

        client.on('reconnecting', () => {
            this.logger.log('redis client is reconnecting to server...');
        });


        client.on('ready', () => {
            this.logger.log('redis client is ready');
        });

        client.on('end', () => {
            this.logger.log('redis client connection closed');
        });

        client.on('error', (error: Error) => {
            this.logger.error(error, 'redis client received an error');
        });
    }

    async onModuleDestroy(): Promise<void> {
        this.logger.log('App Module Destroyes, redis will disconnect now.');
        await this.redisStore.client.quit();
    }

}


import { REDIS_EXPIRY } from '@config';
import { Inject, Injectable, Logger, Scope } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Cache } from 'cache-manager';
import flat from 'flat';
import { RedisStore} from 'cache-manager-ioredis-yet';
import { CACHE_MANAGER } from '@nestjs/cache-manager';

@Injectable({scope:Scope.DEFAULT})
export class RedisService {
    private readonly logger = new Logger('RedisClient');

    // Ref: https://github.com/Heaty566/mychess/blob/main/server/src/utils/redis/redis.service.ts
    constructor(@Inject(CACHE_MANAGER) private redisRepository: Cache) {
    
    }
    async setObjectByKey(key: string, value: Record<string, any>, expired: number=REDIS_EXPIRY): Promise<void> {
        const flatValue: Record<string, any> = flat(value);
        const convertToJson = JSON.stringify(flatValue);
        return await this.redisRepository.set(key, convertToJson, expired).catch(e=>{
            this.logger.log(`Error During SetObjectByKey in Redis Service : ${JSON.stringify(e)}`);
            throw new Error(e);
        });
    }

    async reset(){
        return await this.redisRepository.reset();
    }

    async deleteByKey(key: string): Promise<void> {
        return await this.redisRepository.del(key).catch(e=>{
            this.logger.log(`Error During SetObjectByKey in Redis Service : ${JSON.stringify(e)}`);
            throw new Error(e);
        });
    }

    async getObjectByKey<T>(key: string): Promise<any> {
        try{
            const data = await this.redisRepository.get<string>(key)
            if(data === undefined || data === null){
                return data;
            }
            const convertToJson = flat.unflatten(JSON.parse(data));
            return convertToJson;
        }catch(e){
            this.logger.log(`Error During getObjectByKey in Redis Service : ${JSON.stringify(e)}`);
                throw new Error(e);
        }

    }
}
import { Global, Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { RedisService } from './redis.service';
@Global()

@Module({
    providers: [
        RedisService,
    ],
    exports: [RedisService],
})
export class RedisModule { }
```

I am using nest 9.4.0 and added cache manager to utilize redis. but every request redis is creating new client connection and beacuse of that microsoft azure redis server reach max clients

tried different approach to create redis service but same issue. I was expecting one singleton service with one connection per app